# How to add language highlighting tags to fenced code blocks in markdown

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I'd like to create a vim function to automatically add the code highlight tags, e.g. ```` ```python ```` and ```` ``` ```` around fenced code blocks to have syntax highlighting in my markdown previewer (I'm using `iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim` which is great). The best I've got so far is using `^\S.*$\n\(^$\n\)\+\(\s\{4,}.*$\n\|^$\n\)\+` to match the code blocks **and** a preceding non-empty line. I then go on to use (defined as a function)

````
let lang = input('enter the highlighting language : ') 
inoremap jj <Esc>
g@^\S.*$\n\(^$\n\)\+\(\s\{4,}.*$\n\|^$\n\)\+@ execute "normal :delmarks!" | execute "normal jmai```".lang."jjld$}Pmb" | 'a,'bs/^\s\{4}//g
````

trying to add the highlighting flags and removing the four leading spaces. However, it is not working properly since `}` in the third line jumps to the first empty line inside the code blocks instead of the end. For example, for the code blocks (four leading spaces are explicitly shown)

```
    def foo(*args):
        print args

    foo(1, 2, 3) # (1, 2, 3)
```

the above function ends up with

````
```python
def foo(*args):
  print args
```
    foo(1, 2, 3) # (1, 2, 3)
````

How do I properly jump to the end of the match and fix the function? Or does anybody has  better alternatives in mind?

Comment: If you're matching a whole block with a single regex, I believe the best way to transform it will be to use a `:s` command. To unindent the block, you can use `\=` on the replacement and the `substitute()` function to perform the further substitution.

Comment: I can write an answer for that, but I'm still missing a piece of it... Why do you match on an unindented line for the first line? What is that trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you just do `:call search('', 'e')`

Comment: @filbranden The purpose of adding a preceding non-empty line in the match pattern is to match each code blocks with empty lines inside only once. This extra line is not what I want, though. My knowledge on vim is still limited, and I have to cook what I have. I am still not able to implement your idea of using `:s` to do the workflow, adding language tags first and then unindent in one time. An complete answer will be appreciated!

Comment: @Rich May be it is part of your complete answer. Replacing `}` with `:call search('', 'e')`  in my `cmd` part, however, fails to jump to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This substitution works:

````
:%s/\v^ {4}.*\ze(\n( {4}.*\ze)?)*/\="```".lang."\r".substitute(submatch(0), '\v(^|\n\zs) {4}', '', 'g')."\r```"/
````

Note that even though the regex is not anchored at the *first* line that starts with four spaces. But that is fine if we're using it with a `:%s` command, since that command will not rescan text it has already replaced, so it will perform the substitution only once on each such block.

For the replacement, we're using `\=` to use an expression and then the `substitite()` function to strip four space indent from each of the lines.

Let's break it down. First, the search pattern:

```
/\v^ {4}.*\ze(\n( {4}.*\ze)?)*
```

And let's look at one item at a time:

- `\v`: Use "verymagic", so we don't need to use backslashes to escape most special symbols.
- `^ {4}.*`: Match a line starting with at least four spaces.
- `\ze`: End the match at this point. We'll end the match at the last `\ze` we find. This ensures we will always end the match on an indented line and not one a blank line that follows.
- `(\n...)*`: Matches zero or more additional lines of the match inside this group.
- `(...)?`: Make the additional match optional, so that we'll match blank lines, where a `\n` is followed by another `\n`.
- `{4}.*\ze`: This is exactly the same match from the start, we're again matching a line indented by four spaces. When we do, we set the end of the match to the end of this last line matched.

Now for the replacement:

````
\="```".lang."\r".substitute(submatch(0), '\v(^|\n\zs) {4}', '', 'g')."\r```"
````

Breaking it down:

- `\=`: Use an expression for the replacement.
- ```` "```".lang."\r" ````: This is the header line, using three backquotes followed by the language name in the `lang` variable, which you got with `input()`, then a newline.
- `substitute(...)`: Do a further substitution inside the replacement.
- `submatch(0)`: The text that matched the pattern.
- `'\v(^|\n\zs) {4}'`: This regex matches the four initial spaces, either at the beginning of the string, or at the beginning of a line (right after a newline character.) See [`:help string-match`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#string-match) for details on how we need to match the `\n`s explicitly with `substitute()`.
- `''`: Replace the spaces with nothing, to remove that extra indentation.
- `'g'`: Replace all matches, in all lines that start with four spaces.
- ```` ."\r```" ````: End by adding a newline followed by the three backquotes at the end of the block.

Comment: Great thanks! It does the magic! The search pattern in `substitute()` seems to be inconsistent with that in `:s`. While your  `'\v(^|\n\zs) {4}'` correctly remove indenting, `\v^ {4}` which works in `:s` fails here.

Comment: @KevinPowell Yeah in `substitute()` the `^` anchor only matches the start of the whole string. I think that's documented somewhere... 

Comment: I see. In this way, `substitute()` is similar to `'<,'>s` in visual selection in that, with `g` flag, even a single anchor will do the replacement for every line.

Comment: @KevinPowell See [`:help string-match`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#string-match) for details on how we need to match the `\n`s explicitly with `substitute()`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!